# Matchstick Puzzle: 6758-267=3519

Tags: matches

Move **exactly 3** matches to correct the equation.

Reads **6758-267=3519**

[image]

There are no spaces, just some room for possible matches. In the end we ignore all spaces. Digits that are not seperated by a plus, minus or equals to depict a number.

I think this is a hard one, if asking a person to solve with real matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very mildly lateral

> 6136 - 2617 = 3519
>
>  [image]

Comment: This is actually the one intended. Good job!

Comment: Good answer, "There are no spaces, just some room for possible matches." i.m.o. clearly hinted that 'mildly lateral' was intended.

Comment: @Retudin yeah, I noticed that, too, but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 10):

Solution:

> 3786 - 267 = 3519

Graphically:

> [image: 3786 - 267 = 3519 match puzzle solution]

Comment: Wow, great! I didn't expect to find 2 other solutions.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way to do it (very similar to fljx)

> 5786 - 267 = 5519

Graphically

> [image]

Answer (score -6):

Very wildly lateral

> [image: funny solution]

> 6186 - 261 ≠ 3519

Comment: If we don't have a codified universal rule yet against changing = to ≠ in matchstick puzzles, we should. It's the most boring, unoriginal "solution" there is.

Comment: I wrote "to correct the equation". Is it still an equation using ≠ ? I'd say not.